# Commit QSqlRelationalTableModel model changes to database

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel, qsqlrelationaltablemodel

I've modified the relational table model at 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-relationaltablemodel-relationaltablemodel-cpp.html

I want to be able to save my changes to my database, but it only saves the first two columns, not the primary key lookup row. Also, I can't delete the rows. I've searched but haven't found any information about how to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Sample data I use is:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` ( `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `DrinkType` TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1,'Non-alcoholic');
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (2,'Alcoholic');
CREATE TABLE "drinks" ( `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `Name` TEXT NOT NULL, `Type` INTEGER );
INSERT INTO `drinks` VALUES (1,'Coca Cola',1);
INSERT INTO `drinks` VALUES (2,'Pilsner',2);
```

My code:

```
def addRecord():
    model.insertRow(model.rowCount())

def delRecord():
    model.removeRow(view.currentIndex().row())
    model.select()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("QRelationalSqlTableModel")

con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
con.setDatabaseName('drinks.db')
con.open()

model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent = window)
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
model. setTable('drinks')
model.setRelation(2, QtSql.QSqlRelation('category', 'id', 'drinktype'))
model.select()

model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Name')
model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Type of drink')

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
view.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(view))
view.hideColumn(0)
view.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
view.setColumnWidth(2, 150)

vbox.addWidget(view)
btnAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Add record")
btnAdd.clicked.connect(addRecord)
vbox.addWidget(btnAdd)
btnDel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Delete record")
btnDel.clicked.connect(delRecord)
vbox.addWidget(btnDel)

window.setLayout(vbox)
window.resize(430, 250)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is because you are using an inappropriate strategy, if you use `OnManualSubmit` you must call the method `submitAll()` so that the changes are recorded in the database, if you do not want to do it it is better to use `OnRowChange`, with this strategy the changes will be made when after adding the pressures values ​​enter or select another row.

If you want to delete a row from the database you must use `deleteRowFromTable()`, you are using `removeRow()` but this only removes the row in the view but not in the database so an instant later the data is refreshed showing itself new the row.

```
def addRecord():
    model.insertRow(model.rowCount())
    view.scrollToBottom()

def delRecord():
    model.deleteRowFromTable(view.currentIndex().row())
    model.select()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("QRelationalSqlTableModel")

con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
con.setDatabaseName('drinks.db')
con.open()

model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent = window)
model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnRowChange)
model. setTable('drinks')
model.setRelation(2, QtSql.QSqlRelation('category', 'id', 'drinktype'))
model.select()

model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Name')
model.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Type of drink')

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
view.setModel(model)
view.setItemDelegate(QtSql.QSqlRelationalDelegate(view))
view.hideColumn(0)
view.setColumnWidth(1, 150)
view.setColumnWidth(2, 150)

vbox.addWidget(view)
btnAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Add record")
btnAdd.clicked.connect(addRecord)
vbox.addWidget(btnAdd)
btnDel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Delete record")
btnDel.clicked.connect(delRecord)
vbox.addWidget(btnDel)

window.setLayout(vbox)
window.resize(430, 250)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Blessed be! Thank you very much.